# Californium build failure using maven

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, coap

I am trying to build the Californium repository https://github.com/eclipse/californium using maven. Typing "mvn clean install" gives the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.eclipse.californium:californium-core:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 29, column 18
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Root
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Core
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Proxy
[INFO] Californium (Cf) OSGi Bundle
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestClient
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestChecker
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestServer
[INFO] Cf-HelloWorldClient
[INFO] Cf-HelloWorldServer
[INFO] Cf-SecureServer
[INFO] Cf-ExampleCrossProxy
[INFO] Cf Benchmark Server
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Californium (Cf) Root 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.californium:element-connector:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Root ............................. FAILURE [0.097s]
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Core ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Proxy ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Californium (Cf) OSGi Bundle ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestClient ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestChecker ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-PlugtestServer ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-HelloWorldClient ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-HelloWorldServer ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-SecureServer ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-ExampleCrossProxy .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf Benchmark Server ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.894s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 26 18:29:52 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project root: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.eclipse.californium:root:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.californium:element-connector:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I tried different things but still Idon't know how to fix this errors and go on with my work. Can anyone help me?

MORE INFO:
Downloding and installing (mvn clean install) Californium Element Connector https://github.com/eclipse/californium.element-connector.git brings the build of Californium a little farther, but there are still some dependencies missing. I think that one of these is californium Scandium, but after I downloaded it, I found out that it also has some building problems...

Actually, all I want to use is the repo caled californium.tools (https://github.com/eclipse/californium.tools), which is based on Californium. I checked the pom.xml of californium.tools, and it already includes the required dependencies. However,when I build, I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Tools
[INFO] Cf-ConsoleClient
[INFO] Cf-GUIClient
[INFO] Cf-CoAPBench
[INFO] Cf-ExampleServer
[INFO] Cf-ResourceDirectory
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Californium (Cf) Tools 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ tools ---
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/ceccog/californium.tools/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:test-jar (default) @ tools ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/ceccog/californium.tools/target/tools-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ tools >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ tools <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar (attach-sources) @ tools ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ tools ---
[INFO] Installing /home/ceccog/californium.tools/pom.xml to /home/ceccog/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/californium/tools/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tools-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/ceccog/californium.tools/target/tools-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /home/ceccog/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/californium/tools/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/tools-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Cf-ConsoleClient 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.californium:scandium:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Californium (Cf) Tools ............................ SUCCESS [0.886s]
[INFO] Cf-ConsoleClient .................................. FAILURE [0.078s]
[INFO] Cf-GUIClient ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-CoAPBench ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-ExampleServer .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Cf-ResourceDirectory .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.161s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 02 11:42:57 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cf-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.eclipse.californium:cf-client:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.californium:scandium:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :cf-client
```

Comment: Did you configure the repositories ... like the README.md file says?  The clue is that the dependencies are on SNAPSHOT releases, and you won't find SNAPSHOT releases in Maven Central.

Comment: Yes, I did! The readme.md says to include in the pom.xml of my projects certain dependencies. Actually, I want to build and use californium.tools <https://github.com/eclipse/californium.tools>. Its pom.xml already has those dependencies. I edited my question, including the buld errors for californium.tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** it looks like the maven repositories are online now and the bug in cf-secure has been fixed. So only step 4 is required to install the californium tools.

The repositories mentioned in README.md do not seem to be online yet. Therefore maven can not resolve the dependencies automatically. The trick is to build and install the maven artifacts directly from source in the appropriate order.

So in order to get californium.tools working:

1. install org.eclipse.californium:element-connector

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/eclipse/californium.element-connector.git
   cd californium.element-connector
   mvn clean install
   ```
2. install org.eclipse.californium:scandium

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/eclipse/californium.scandium.git
   cd californium.scandium
   mvn clean install
   ```
3. install org.eclipse.californium:californium-core

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/eclipse/californium.git
   cd californium
   mvn -pl :californium-core -am clean install
   ```

   Note that we are only building the californium-core submodule (with the `-pl :californium-core -am` flag), since there is a bug in cf-secure which causes the build to fail.
4. build the Californium tools

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/eclipse/californium.tools.git
   cd californium.tools
   mvn -pl :cf-browser,:cf-coapbench,:cf-rd,:cf-server -am clean install
   ```

   We need to exclude cf-client since it has a bug which makes the build fail.

To run any of the tools, just `cd californium.tools/run` and `java -jar ...` the appropriate jar.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Running only step 4 worked fine for what I wanted to do. The other examples and parts of Californium still have some troubles, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the project was recently created at eclipse.

Hudson is populating the maven repository now.